# What Java compareTo function does

Tags: java, php, spring-mvc

I'm migrating a project from Java code to PHP, but some Java code is Alien to me. May i know what this Java code does? And how can i "interpret" this in PHP?

```
//contentList array
contentsList.sort((ClassBook c1, ClassBook c2)->c1.getClassDate().compareTo(c2.getClassDate()));
```

Thank You!

Comment: It quite literally sorts the list by comparing `c1` to `c2` using a custom comparator function, which is probably implemented in `ClassBook` class.

Comment: `compareTo` is as the name suggests, comparing two values. In your case it compares 2 dates. One is maybe earlier than the other and vice versa

Comment: If you just type 'java compareTo' in google you find really good answers in just the first few links. The javadoc is always a good place to start.

Comment: What is the possible approach in PHP?

Comment: @Eljay that may even be another research worth, as mentioned before, just google: *Php compare dates*

Answer (score 1):

Compares ClassBook c1 with the ClassBook c2 for order. Besides, it looks the date field for comparison. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: Q1: After that comparison will it return the latest one or the oldest one? based on the date comparison.
Q2: Sorting by what (name, index)?

Comment: @Eljay The whole expression `contentsList.sort(...)` basically says "sort `contentsList` by class date".

Comment: We can think as number and smallest date is first in here.